# Missing Javascript assets on production deployment of Ruby on Rails app, all is fine under WEBrick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, apache, postgresql

Missing Javascript assets on production deployment of Ruby on Rails app, all is fine under WEBrick.

I have this standard Rails app I'm trying to deploy.

The app loads fine but all Javascript has gone missing. If I load the exact same app with WEBrick all is fine when connecting to that on port 3000.

Refresh the apache app, no Javascript, refresh the WEBrick instance Javascript ok.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you run apache server on server (production env) and Webrick locally (development env). try to run locally `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`. I think you get the same error. This does not solve your problem but should help to reproduce a problem on local machine.

Comment: How serve static assets  in production env? Please post `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, it got me asking questions in all the right places and I've answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Apparently this is a non-standard Rails app. It seems it's looking for some assets in /var/www/mywebsite/public which aren't there.

Had a chat with the developer and you have to do a symlink from the gem install directory to you apache website.

ln -s /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/yourrubyversion/gems/yourgemandversion/public

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are deploying the application, typically you will need to pre-compile the assets in production environment.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html